# Replacing &apos; and similar tags in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove the tags similar to & apos; and & lt;

```
 pattern=Pattern.compile("&apos;");
 match=pattern.matcher(line);
 match.replaceAll("");
```

But it doesn't work . I also tried :

```
line=line.replace("&","");
line=line.replace("apos","");
line=line.replace(";","");
```

But this time , it replaces only the ; delimitor and not the & and apos ....

Comment: Why do you want to remove them?

Comment: I have an XML file with these tags in it... And while parsing SAXParser ignores all the characters before these tags...

Comment: Sounds like it's not a valid XML file. While the answers below will fix the current problem, you might want to investigate the root cause of the invalid XML being generated in the first place.

Comment: Yes  u r correct . The xml is nothing but the result set from Bing Search API... Since my application doesn't require the XML to be valid , i does not bother me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try following regex to remove following patterns: `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&apos;` `&`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("&(lt;|apos;|gt;|)");
```

**TESTING:**

```
Matcher m = pattern.matcher("abc &def &apos; xyz&lt; &gt; mno");
System.out.printf("line=[%s]\n", m.replaceAll(""));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
line=[abc def  xyz  mno]
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using regexp tryout StringEscapeUtils from Apache http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html quite handy for many similar purposes

Comment: Thank you . I'll use it in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

because it is not a valid regular expression. a valid regular expression must have the following-

one '&' sign at start, any text non numerical and end with a ';' sign. Something like (not precisely-

/(&)([a-z][A-Z])+(;)/

Happy New Year.